# Convert a Number to String

Tags: java

I am trying to print my number **12386876764.34** and I want my output as the same. I tried the following to print my number, but could not find a way to print the same. Please provide a solution for this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println((12386876764.34*100)/100);
    System.out.println(Math.round(12386876764.34*100)/100);
    System.out.println((new BigDecimal((12386876764.34*100)/100)).toPlainString());
    System.out.println((new BigDecimal(Math.round(12386876764.34*100)/100)).toPlainString());
}
```

**Output:**
1.238687676434E10
12386876764
12386876764.340000152587890625
12386876764

Comment: `System.out.println(String.format("%.2f", 12386876764.34));`

Comment: Use the string constructor for `BigDecimal`. Your numeric literal is losing precision going through the `double` constructor. `new java.math.BigDecimal("12386876764.34")`

Comment: This is *not* the same as the question it was closed as being a duplicate of, because that one is about formatting floating-point numbers - this question calls for avoiding the use of floating-point numbers altogether.

Comment: Clarify your question title next time so it doesn't get mistaken for duplicate. Just a tip.

Comment: This *is* the same question. A `double` has more than enough precision to represent the value. `System.out.printf("%.2f%n", 12386876764.34D);` The decision to use `BigDecimal` is based on the application. For engineering and computation of physical models, use `float` or `double`. For finance, use `BigDecimal`.